# Changing the font size of a bibliography using BibTeX with the amsrefs package

Tags: bibliographies, fontsize, amsrefs

I am using BibTeX with the `amsrefs` package to create a bibliography.  The output of the bibliography looks to be of a slightly smaller font size that that of the ambient document, and it's imperative that these font sizes be equal.  I have already tried

```
{\normalsize\bibliography{mybib}}
```

to no avail.  Can anyone please steer me in the right direction?  Thanks!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The font is controlled by the `\biblistfont` command; simply redefine this macro in your preamble (to change the default `\footnotesize`) by adding the following lines:

```
\renewcommand{\biblistfont}{%
  \normalfont
  \normalsize
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU!!  I wish I could upvote this answer ten more times...you just saved me the biggest headache. :)

Comment: Is there something similar to change the size of title "References" that is being generated?